# Are concepts as type names in function declarations valid in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code compiles fine on both gcc and clang (trunk with -std=c++20) but errors on msvc (19.27 /std:c++latest).

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept subable = requires(T lhs, T rhs) { lhs - rhs; };

auto sub(subable auto x, subable auto y) {
    return x - y;
}


int main() {
    const auto z = sub(4, 5);
}
```

afaik the above code should be valid in C++20, it was in the concepts-ts. Is this a case of microsoft being behind other implementations? (C++20 isn't even out yet after all) or did this not make it into 20?

Comment: "*it was in the concepts-ts*" No, it was not.

Comment: @NicolBolas Was it not? Damn, I swear I read somewhere that it was. Why then is it in gcc and clang?

Comment: Not with *that* syntax, it wasn't.

Comment: C++20 standard is in final form since 4th of September and will be officially publish at the end of year (probably December). https://isocpp.org/std/status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concepts cannot be used to replace typenames in C++20. However, that's *not* what your code is doing. You are using abbreviated function template syntax, by declaring the type of the parameter to use the placeholder type `auto`. Abbreviated function templates can be constrained by applying a type-concept name to the `auto`-declared parameter (some versions of VS have not implemented abbreviated function template syntax).

But this is *not* the syntax that was used in Concepts-TS, where a type concept would *replace* the typename.

Comment: Right so `template<concept_name T>`?

Comment: @Firefly: That's a *template* parameter, not a *function* parameter. Template parameters can do that; function parameters cannot. Such a template parameter declares `T` to be a *typename*; a function parameter is a *variable*. They're not the same thing. Template parameters can also do `template<type_concept auto value>`, which allows the deduction of the *variable* `value`, constrained by `type_concept`.

Comment: sorry, I think i'm using the terminology wrong, I get the difference between a variable and a typename, I was asking whether that was what you meant by "replace typenames". I didn't know it could do that but I did know about "abbreviated function templates" (just not their name). So `template<type_concept auto value>` is like `template<int value>`? Where `int` is instead anything which satisfies `type_concept`?